# Add a button in user orders view requesting info about current order Drupal Commerce 7

Tags: 7, commerce, views

I have an automated e-shop in Drupal 7 and drupal commerce.

I am trying to add an action button in user orders view, which on "pressing" by every current user is sending email(alert with replacement tokens about current selected order) to administrator of eshop.

Any ideas to implement action button?

I tried VBO and Views Send modules but i didn't succeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

1. Create a component with the **Action** *Send mail*. Use tokens to customize the subject and message body as you like.
2. Edit the view and use VBO to trigger the rules component.

Comment: Thats it.Thanks! I would need also  in user orders view in each row a button for every row to achieve above function(VBO provides only one button and checkboxes to each order).